# The stored procedure output is returning null

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, java-stored-procedures

I was asked to write a stored procedure for calculating the net salary of the employee if we pass 
employee Id as a parameter and the formulas were given and the I had to write a Java program for the same.
I write this procedure in MY SQL WORKBENCH first and then wrote the Java program in eclipse IDE. 
When I am executing this procedure in MY SQL WORKBENCH it is returning NULL as the result rather than the salary of the employee.
In the output of Java program also the Salary of the employee is printed as 0.0 for all the employees.
[This the schema of the employee table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idKne.png)
After this Stored procedure I ran the below queries in QUERY SCRIPT:

**call Get_Salary(101, @SALARY);
SELECT @SALARY;**

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost` PROCEDURE Get_Salary(IN ID int, OUT SALARY double )
BEGIN
    declare Sal, e_commission, Gross_Sal, IT double;
    select Salary,Commission into Sal, e_commission from employee where Employee_id = ID;
    set Gross_Sal= Sal + e_commission;
    if e_commission is null then
       set IT= 0.1 * Gross_Sal;
    else if e_commission < 500 then
       set IT= 0.15 * Gross_Sal;
    else
       set IT= 0.2 * Gross_Sal;
    end if;
    set SALARY = Gross_Sal - IT;

END
```

Comment: it would be more helpful if you provide table schemas.

Comment: Yes, so I have attached the Table schema in my question.

Answer (score 0):

You had a simple issue yet very minor to observe. Anyway, your output variable Salary has the same name as selecting value from table. So, basically you are selecting Salary from employee as well as you are having a local variable Salary. Despite the different cases, they are similar.

Also, you have forgot an `end if` at the end. Each if needs an End.

[Here is the reference for study](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html)

Comment: When I am adding another end if it's showing error.

Comment: Have you pasted the above code exactly from the workbench or you missed some lines? I was putting end if right after existing end if. Additionally, you don't have to use: DEFINER=root@localhost` (optional) and back tick at the end of localhost is also generating error.